# STM32F1 FreeRTOS osDelay (also vTaskDelay) make task stop running

Tags: stm32, freertos

I am using FreeRTOS with STM32F103C8T6 (code generated by CubeMX) and experiencing very strange behavior in my application while using osDelay or vTaskDelay functions.

Structure of my app is 3 tasks.
Task1: reads GPS data and provides location in queue.
Task2: reads location and sends it over uart to the outside system
Task3: reads GPIO pins and responds to that by changing some other pins

All works fine until I put osDelay value greater then 100ms inside, then task stops working.
As said if I put osDelay(100) all works without any issue.

I have checked stack overflow and there is none.
Currently monitoring for stackoverflow inside callback and high watermark with uxTaskGetStackHighWaterMark but none of them report anything.

Any hint ? What could be cause of such issue?

Comment: There is quite some missing information here, but for starters, what are your different task priorities?

Comment: Sorry for the missing par (ask what you think I should add.All three tasks share the same priority.